# Quickest way to open jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

Every day, I repeat the same procedure over and over to open a Jupyter notebook.

1. I navigate with File Explorer to my work folder `C:\Users\MYSELF\WORKFOLDER`
2. Open command prompt there
3. Enter the command `jupyter notebook` or `jupyter lab`

If you don't have jupyter in your python base environment it becomes even more painful because you need to activate some virtual environment.

**Is there a quicker way?**

I'd love to have an icon on my desktop that I can just click on!

Comment: your can create a shortcut in the taskbar or desktop that executes this instruction

Comment: a bat file will do. first `cd` to the directory and call `jupyter notebook` or  `jupyter lab` from there. you can as well activate the enviroment after `cd` into the directionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right-click on your desktop `New -> Shortcut`. Then enter the following for the location:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k cd C:\Users\MYSELF\WORKFOLDER && jupyter notebook
```

This will start a command prompt and execute the two commands `cd C:\Users\MYSELF\WORKFOLDER` and `jupyter notebook`.

Click `Next` and you can then give that shortcut a name and create it with a click on `Finish`.